# logger middleware throws "TypeError: Cannot read property 'NullLogger' of undefined"

Tags: angular

angular cli doesn't create the Component will , it is just console this message

**Cann't read property 'NullLogger' of undefined**

Comment: what is your cli local version ?

Comment: i looked at the package.json it i s ^1.4.9 i think

Answer (score 23, accepted):

try this : `npm install --save @angular/cli@latest`
at your package.json directory .

Answer (score 3):

I think it can be the problem with `Angular CLI` or `npm` versions, so try:

`npm install npm@latest -g`

`npm install @angular/cli@latest --save`

Note: may be you will need to install `npm` with `sudo`:

`sudo npm install npm@latest -g`

Comment: if I save the package locally, how can I build the project using ng serve? When I do that the command ng is not recognized by windows...

Comment: @pedro.olimpio Hi, to work with Angular CLI, you should have both CLI versions (global and local) to be installed

Comment: @pedro.olimpio, No problems, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

In windows , uninstalling and installing angular cli (using npm) did not solve this problem for me.
I solved it by uninstalling node v8 and downgrading to node  v6.And then taking the latest angular cli version.

Answer (score 0):

**npm install --save @angular/cli@latest**   This worked but I had to bring up my Command window as administrator.